# Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android-studio, environment-variables

I have installed Android Studio and JDK.  I have set my variable to the JDK folder.  Now, when launching the program I receive an error message stating, "The environment variable JAVA_HOME (with the value of C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0) does not point to a valid JVM Installation.
Can you please assist with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Go in the console and `echo %PATH%` and see if your JDK is in there somewhere, if not you'll need to add it to your `%PATH%`. If it's there, use the path listed

Answer (score 0):

That path to jdk1.8.0 is likely wrong.  Are you *sure* its ProgramFiles and not "Program Files" and that the rest of your path is correct?

Answer (score 0):

hi guys i to occurred with same problem but i resolved as if your JAVA_HOME JDK is referring with another IDE then this problem will occur , so first delete existing java_home and take a location of ur jdk/bin and paste into PATH field in environment> system variables after setting into that path field save it then start your ADK it will work,.